# How to set 6 physical, 6 hyper threading total 12 cores to hyper-v virtual machine - A parameter cannot be found HwThreadCountPerCore

Tags: virtual-machine, powershell, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I have windows server 2012 R2 on physical dedicated server

I have created a virtual machine via  Hyper-V  and installed Windows server 2019 in it

My dedicated physical server has 12+12 total 24 cores

12 core is physical and 12 core is hyper threading

From dedicated server's hyper-v interface, there is no option to set how many physical cores and how many logical cores for the created virtual machine

So I am trying to set number of threads per core via the command below from powershell (running as administrator) in the dedicated physical server

`Set-VMProcessor -VMName aa -HwThreadCountPerCore 2`  //aa is the name of hyper v machine

However this command is giving the below error but it should work

What is the error and why it is not working?

How can i set X amount of physical cores and Y amount of logical cores?

```
    Set-VMProcessor : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'HwThreadCountPerCore'.
At line:1 char:28
+ Set-VMProcessor -VMName aa -HwThreadCountPerCore 2
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-VMProcessor], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.SetVMProcessorCommand
```

This command has worked on my personal computer which is Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

By using Hyper-V from inside a VM, you are trying to use
[Nested Virtualization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization).

The documentation gives these conditions for using Nested Virtualization:

> - The Hyper-V host and guest must both be Windows Server 2016/Windows 10 Anniversary Update or later.
> - VM configuration version 8.0 or greater.
> - An Intel processor with VT-x and EPT technology -- nesting is currently Intel-only.
> - There are some differences with virtual networking for second-level virtual machines.

As Windows server 2016 is the first version to support it, it cannot work on
Windows Server 2012 R2. You will need to upgrade the host to at least
Windows server 2016.

Comment: No you understood the question incorrectly. I have installed a VM on to my physical dedicated server via hyper-v. So it is not a nested virtualization. Physical dedicated server is windows server 2012 r2, VM via hyper-v is windows server 2019

Comment: I have updated the question and made it more clear @harrymc